# why i get this error in FLEX-LEXER code ? ( undefined definition {IDF} )

Tags: c, flex-lexer

**Here is the code of flex - with c language**

Declaration

```
%{
#include<stdio.h>
%}
```

regular expression

```
%%

first [A-Z]
body ([0-9a-zA-Z](?!__)|[_])*
end [0-9a-zA-Z]

IDF ({first}{body}{end})

{IDF}
{
    if ( yyleng > 10 ) {
        printf("Lexical Error : IDF LEN > 10 is equal to %s", yytext);
    } else {
        printf("IDF: %s ", yytext);
    }
}

%%
```

the rest of c code

```
int yywrap(){}

int main()
{
    printf("give idf : ");
    yylex();
    return 0;
}
```

i think the problem is in this scope

```
first [A-Z]
body ([0-9a-zA-Z](?!__)|[_])*
end [0-9a-zA-Z]

IDF ({first}{body}{end})

{IDF}
{
    if ( yyleng > 10 ) {
        printf("Lexical Error : IDF LEN > 10 is equal to %s", yytext);
    } else {
        printf("IDF: %s ", yytext);
    }
}
```

Im using CODE BLOCKS ,
I tried this codes on cmd
`flex test.c` after this line I got that error
**undefined definition {IDF}**

Answer (score 1):

The definitions of named regular expressions go into the definition section (the first one), not the second one.

You need to move the first `%%` after the definition of `IDF`.

The second section is called the translation section.
The only things that are allowed there are unnamed regular expressions followed by actions.